# How do you set Allow Countries directly in the database, programmatically or using n98-magerun?

Tags: magento-enterprise, configuration, database, programming

I have a list of over 200 countries I need to allow for an EE 1.13 site. I'd prefer not to do this through the admin interface because it is tedious and I am error prone. Is it possible to set Allow Countries directly in the database, programmatically or using n98-magerun?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be edited in the db. A few thoughts, though:

- **Don't edit the db directly**. Because this is a config setting you can call saveConfig(); Make an upgrade script (example saveConfig below)
- This value won't exist in `core_config_data` if you've never saved it in the admin panel.

[image]

**Example:**

```
$config = Mage::getModel('core/config');
$config->saveConfig('general/country/allow', "AF,AX,AL,DZ", 'default', 0);
```

Comment: Use n98-magerun if you i.e. migrate a live system to a development system to change settings. In case of deliver system configurations with an update it's better to bundle the config with a upgrade script.